# Insert format/components between words in i18n-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, i18n-js

I'm using i18n-js in a React Native app, also Expo and `expo-localization`. Although the library provides interpolation for translated strings, I did not find a way to insert React or React Native components or styles between words to provide better formatting.

For example:

```js
// en.js
// ...
{
  "bold": "A word will be <B>bold</B> inside this string."
}
    
// create the i18n string
const B = (props) => <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{props.children}</Text>
console.log( I18n.t("bold") );
```

Expected:
A word will be **bold** inside this string

What I got:
`A word will be <B>bold</B> inside this string`

How can I add styles to some translated words?

Comment: Did you solve this?